# Unix decompress files parallel and store them

Tags: unix, parallel-processing

I have a directory `/user/test` with 2000 compressed files.
I want to check if any given file has 5 records then I have to store it in decompressed format.

I am able to do it serially but it is taking a lot of time to finish this job.

Serially I am doing as below:

```
for i in `find /user/test -iname "abc*.gz"`;
do
    lines=`zcat $i | wc -l`
    if [ $lines = 5 ]; then
        fname=`basename -s .$file_ext $i`
        echo "copying $fname to new path"
        `zcat $i > new_path/$fname`
        cnt=$((cnt+1))
    else
        echo "Ignoring file $i. Expecting 5 records. It has more or less records"
    fi
done
```

I want to do the same in parallel.

I tried exploring GNU `parallel` but am seeing an error. I tried below command

```
find /user/test -iname "abc*.gz" |
parallel 'zcat {} | awk 'NR == 5 {print $0}' < {}.txt'
```

Above command is not working throwing error.

Comment: Please consider reporting the error you got so to help people to better understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested:

```
doit() {
  zcat "$@" | awk 'NR == 5 {print $0}'
}
export -f doit
find /user/test -iname "abc*.gz" |
  parallel doit
```

Based on what you do serially:

```
doit() {
    i="$1"
    lines=`zcat $i | wc -l`
    if [ $lines = 5 ]; then
        fname=`basename -s .$file_ext $i`
        echo "copying $fname to new path"
        `zcat $i > new_path/$fname`
    else
        echo "Ignoring file $i. Expecting 5 records. It has more or less records"
    fi
}
export -f doit
export file_ext 

find /user/test -iname "abc*.gz" | parallel doit
```

The general idea is to build a bash function that works on a single input. `export` the function (and the variables needed by the function) and run the function in parallel.

The benefit is that it is pretty easy to test the function on a single input.

When writing the function there is a small gotcha: The function cannot write to hardcoded files, because this will create a race condition (multiple instances writing at the same time). So you need to write the function in a way in which this does not happen.